# how to read textbox value for textbox's having dynamic ids?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 inputs as shown below. 1 of them is button another one is textbox. 
qty-input is used to enter quantity of the products and when I click the button using jquery. I update my shopping cart. It works when I hardcode it as 1 but I couldnt figure out how to do it by reading from the textbox without postback.

Code below belongs to 1 product in a partialview and it is displayed in a list and I need to assign id for each created textbox so, this textbox should belongs to button.

when I simply use `var quantity = $('.qty-input').val();`, it works only for the first generated textbox. It means if I want to add 2nd product into the cart, It will confuse because of it has same class. therefore I have to work with Id.
Another Idea can be using angular.js, I saw some examples, it looks pretty easy to implement it but i couldnt figure out how to do it?

jquery or angular.js, I need your help. thanks.

in my partial view

```
     var quantity = 1;
   string addtocartlink = "";
addtocartlink = Url.RouteUrl("AddProductToCart-Catalog", new { productId = Model.Id, shoppingCartTypeId = shoppingCartTypeId, quantity = quantity });

    <div class="cart-input">
           <input class="qty-input" id="@Model.Id" data-val="true" type="text" value="1">
          <input type="button" value="@(addToCartClass)" class="button-2 product-box-add-to-cart-button @addToCartClass" onclick="AjaxCart.addproducttocart_catalog('@addtocartlink');return false;" />
</div>
```

my javascript

```
  addproducttocart_catalog: function (urladd,id) {
        if (this.loadWaiting != false) {
            return;
        }
        this.setLoadWaiting(true);
        var quantity = $(id).val();
        urladd = urladd.substring(0, urladd.length - 1) + quantity;

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: urladd,
            type: 'post',
            success: this.success_process,
            complete: this.resetLoadWaiting,
            error: this.ajaxFailure
        });
    },
```

Comment: you can explore event object. like $(event.target)

Comment: Its a bit unclear from your code. Do you have multiple 'products' displayed in your view with and associated textbox for the quantity and a button to update the cart (in which case your code is incorrect)

Comment: It is a partialview for a productbox which is repeated for each product in the Main view. So with that each product has A quantity textbox and a add to cart Button. If not clear, i will extend with more Code later. Writing on my mobile now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, you have multiple textbox inputs for `Quantity` and associated button. You can handle this using relative selectors and there is no need to add any `id` attributes. Change your html to

```
<div class="cart-input">
    <input class="qty-input" type="text" value="1">
    <input type="button" value="Add to cart" class="button-2 product-box-add-to-cart-button @addToCartClass" data-id="@Model.Id" />
</div>
```

Note the productID value has been added as a `data` attribute in the button. Then the script will be

```
var url = '@Url.RouteUrl("AddProductToCart-Catalog")';
$('.product-box-add-to-cart-button').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  var qty = $(this).closest('.cart-input').find('.qty-input').val();
  $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    data: { productId: id, shoppingCartTypeId: shoppingCartTypeId, quantity: qty },
    success: this.success_process,
    ....
    });
});
```

Side note: I deleted `data-val="true"` from the textbox. This only makes sense if you have an associated `ValidationMessageFor()` in the view which you do not appear to have, and in any case it still allows you to enter `"ABC"` which would obviously fail, and your not even checking if its valid before posting. You should stop using manual html and partials for this, and use an `EditorTemplate` for your model (where the model includes a property `int Quantity`), and use the strongly typed HtmlHelpers to generate your view. Then you can use the `.Valid()` method to check if the quantity is valid before posting (and cancel it if not)

Comment: How can i do it if the js is defined in the seperate file? I am not able get this working if the js is in the seperate file.  var qty = $(this).closest('.cart-input').find('.qty-input').val(); reference is already added

Comment: It will all work fine in a separate file except for the `var url = '@Url.RouteUrl("AddProductToCart-Catalog")';` line of code (razor code is not parsed in external files so you wont get a valid url). You can either (1) put that line in the main view (as a global variable), or (2) add a `data-url="@Url.RouteUrl("AddProductToCart-Catalog")"` to the button and read it as for the `id` value, or (3) create an initialization function in your external file that sets the url.

Comment: Ok. i got it but one thing is not comprehensive for me. How is the data object retreived? It should be related to the model right? as above in my code, addtocartlink was built from Model.

Comment: And why did you use data-id instead of id? does it make any difference?

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand your last comment. Your passing an object (defined by the `data` option) to the server which contains 3 properties (`productId`, `shoppingCartTypeId` and `quantity`). If your POST method has parameters which match them, then they will be bound. Or if it has a parameter which is a model containing 3 matching property names then it will bind to your model.

Comment: Because its the correct usage for for adding arbitary [data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to a html element. In his case your not (and there is no need to) creating a unique identifier for the element for use in a javascript/jquery selector

Comment: sorry about the confusion. I see what you mean about posting 3 elements. only shoppingCartTypeId  was missing in my case. Actually I am having a variable in my view as this var shoppingCartTypeId = (int)ShoppingCartType.ShoppingCart; 

how can i read in the js? I mean is it possible with jquery. of course I can pass it as a paramter to the function but wondering how to do with jquery

Comment: Is it a property of your model? In which case you can use something like `var shoppingCartTypeId = '@Model.ShoppingCart';` (but again if its in an external file you will need to use the techniques I mentioned earlier (of put the value in a hidden input with a unique `id` and read it using `var shoppingCartTypeId = $('#yourID').val();`. But without seeing more code its a bit hard to advise the best method.

Comment: var url = '@Url.RouteUrl("AddProductToCart-Catalog")'; this line is not working VS complains with the error message "CS1012: Too many characters in character literal." I tried  using "@Url.RouteUrl(\"AddProductToCart-Catalog\")"; But \ are included in the string. I dont get how to make this line working. I can hardcode the url of course

Comment: Your approach is perfectly working only mistake in your code looks like with the line in my previous comment. since I have 3 parameters for my route. I should use it as it is in my question addtocartlink = Url.RouteUrl("AddProductToCart-Catalog", new { productId = Model.Id, shoppingCartTypeId = shoppingCartTypeId, quantity = quantity });

redefined data will override and make it working anyway. thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways you can implement it.

a. To get the id , you can simply declare a variable in javascript :

```
var id = '@Model.Id';
```

b. You can assign an attribute to your input element.

```
<input class="qty-input" id="@Model.Id" data-val="true" type="text"    unique-id="qty" value="1">

var id = $("input[unique-id='qty']").attr("id");
```

Comment: This one  var id = $("input[unique-id='qty']").attr('id');  will return me always Id of the first textbox in the list. But I need the Id and the value of the textbox of the product which belongs the clicked button in the list of products.

Comment: That is the reason why attr unique-id was added to input quantity. You may add similar attribute unique-id="product" to the product input and extract the id via $("input[unique-id='product']").attr("id");